# Why does my Python regular expression find two matches?

Tags: python, regex

I am using `[0x]?\d+` to attempt to locate strings of the nature

```
0x10101
0x12341
12321
```

But when I run the regular expression on `0x3`, I get `[u'0', u'x3']`.

It seems (to my untrained eye) that it is matching the shortest sequences? Or is there something wrong with my use of `[]?`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[...]`, which is called a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), matches a single character.

You probably want:

```
(?:0x)?\d+
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you! I will accept when the timer runs down.